# BPMN process isn't being deployed

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I'm following this [camunda bpm tutorial](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/), but my process doesn't show up in the cockpit view, the only different i did it was name of the process, and a different bpmn diagram, but that should affect the correct deployment of the process.

the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>bpm.oeste.mx</groupId>
  <artifactId>cartografia</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>cartografia</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

the  process.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<process-application
    xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/ProcessApplication"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <process-archive name="cartografiaBPM">
    <process-engine>default</process-engine>
    <properties>
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
      <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
    </properties>
  </process-archive>

</process-application>
```

i can see my bpmn in deployments, i see the bpmn file and the diagram but not in the processes tabs.

cartografia.bpmn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="_YY2ScFqPEeaO2tgDdxhJRw" targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="1.2.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd">
  <bpmn2:collaboration id="cartoBPM" name="cartografia bpm">
    <bpmn2:participant id="cartoBPMN" name="Proceso de Captura Cartografica" processRef="Process_6" />
  </bpmn2:collaboration>
  <bpmn2:process id="Process_6" name="cartografia_bpm" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn2:laneSet id="LaneSet_10" name="Lane Set 10">
      <bpmn2:lane id="Lane_7" name="Procesamiento">
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>Task_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
      </bpmn2:lane>
      <bpmn2:lane id="lane_9" name="
&#10;Jefe de Proyecto
&#10;">
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>Task_3</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>ComplexGateway_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>StartEvent_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>Task_4</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>BoundaryEvent_6</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>ExclusiveGateway_2</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>EndEvent_2</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>Task_2</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>UserTask_2</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>SendTask_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
      </bpmn2:lane>
      <bpmn2:lane id="Lane_1" name="Operador
&#10;">
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>ParallelGateway_2</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>UserTask_3</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>ReceiveTask_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>ParallelGateway_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>UserTask_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>BoundaryEvent_1</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
        <bpmn2:flowNodeRef>BoundaryEvent_2</bpmn2:flowNodeRef>
      </bpmn2:lane>
    </bpmn2:laneSet>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="Task_3" name="Recepción y revisón de información">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_30</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_29</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_29" name="" sourceRef="Task_3" targetRef="Task_1" />
    <bpmn2:userTask id="Task_1" name="Tratamiento de información
&#10;">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_29</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_15</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_12</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_12" name="" sourceRef="Task_1" targetRef="Task_2" />
    <bpmn2:inclusiveGateway id="ComplexGateway_1" name="información correcta?">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_13</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_15</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_31</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:inclusiveGateway>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_15" name="informacion topográfica incorrecta" sourceRef="ComplexGateway_1" targetRef="Task_1" />
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Inicio" camunda:formKey="embedded:app:forms/inicio.html">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_30</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_30" name="" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Task_3" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_31" name="información correcta" sourceRef="ComplexGateway_1" targetRef="Task_4" />
    <bpmn2:userTask id="Task_4" name="Verificación GNM">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_31</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:boundaryEvent id="BoundaryEvent_6" name="" attachedToRef="Task_4">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_23</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:timerEventDefinition id="_TimerEventDefinition_8" />
    </bpmn2:boundaryEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_23" name="Esperar verificación" sourceRef="BoundaryEvent_6" targetRef="ExclusiveGateway_2" />
    <bpmn2:exclusiveGateway id="ExclusiveGateway_2" name="Hay incidencias?">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_23</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_14</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_24</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:exclusiveGateway>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_14" name="Hubo incidencias" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway_2" targetRef="UserTask_2" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_24" name="Sin incencias" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway_2" targetRef="EndEvent_2" />
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_2" name="fin">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_24</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_2" name="" sourceRef="Task_4" targetRef="EndEvent_2" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_4" name="geometria incorrecta
&#10;" sourceRef="ComplexGateway_1" targetRef="Task_2" />
    <bpmn2:userTask id="Task_2" name="Asignación de carga de trabajo">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_12</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_11</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_17</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_2" name="Control de calidad">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_14</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_10</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_13</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_13" name="" sourceRef="UserTask_2" targetRef="ComplexGateway_1" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1" name="" sourceRef="Task_2" targetRef="SendTask_1" />
    <bpmn2:sendTask id="SendTask_1" name="Enviar cargas de trabajo correspondiente">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:sendTask>
    <bpmn2:parallelGateway id="ParallelGateway_2">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_8</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_9</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_10</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:parallelGateway>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_3" name="Proceso de ingreso a ICARO">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_7</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_9</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_3" name="" sourceRef="SendTask_1" targetRef="ReceiveTask_1" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_9" name="" sourceRef="UserTask_3" targetRef="ParallelGateway_2" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_10" name="" sourceRef="ParallelGateway_2" targetRef="UserTask_2" />
    <bpmn2:receiveTask id="ReceiveTask_1" name="Notificacion de carga de trabajo pendiente">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_5</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:receiveTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_5" name="" sourceRef="ReceiveTask_1" targetRef="ParallelGateway_1" />
    <bpmn2:parallelGateway id="ParallelGateway_1">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_5</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_6</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_7</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:parallelGateway>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_6" name="" sourceRef="ParallelGateway_1" targetRef="UserTask_1" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_7" name="" sourceRef="ParallelGateway_1" targetRef="UserTask_3" />
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_1" name="Traducción y estructuración">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_6</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_8</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_8" name="" sourceRef="UserTask_1" targetRef="ParallelGateway_2" />
    <bpmn2:boundaryEvent id="BoundaryEvent_1" name="" attachedToRef="UserTask_1">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_11</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:errorEventDefinition id="_ErrorEventDefinition_2" />
    </bpmn2:boundaryEvent>
    <bpmn2:boundaryEvent id="BoundaryEvent_2" name="" attachedToRef="UserTask_3">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_17</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:errorEventDefinition id="_ErrorEventDefinition_3" />
    </bpmn2:boundaryEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_11" name="Interrupcion" sourceRef="BoundaryEvent_1" targetRef="Task_2" />
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_17" name="Interrupcion" sourceRef="BoundaryEvent_2" targetRef="Task_2" />
  </bpmn2:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="cartoBPM">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_3" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="132" y="298" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="132" y="339" width="36" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Task_3" bpmnElement="Task_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="372" y="35" width="100" height="94" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Task_4" bpmnElement="Task_2">
        <dc:Bounds x="456" y="324" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_UserTask_4" bpmnElement="UserTask_2">
        <dc:Bounds x="828" y="420" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_ComplexGateway_2" bpmnElement="ComplexGateway_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="840" y="324" width="50" height="50" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="876" y="363" width="130" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Participant_7" bpmnElement="cartoBPMN" isHorizontal="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="72" y="0" width="1513" height="1106" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Lane_8" bpmnElement="Lane_7" isHorizontal="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="102" y="0" width="1483" height="256" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Lane_10" bpmnElement="lane_9" isHorizontal="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="102" y="255" width="1483" height="323" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_12" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_12" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_Task_3" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="422" y="129" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="422" y="262" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="506" y="262" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="506" y="324" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="419" y="217" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_15" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_15" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ComplexGateway_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_3">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="865" y="324" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="865" y="81" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="472" y="82" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="688" y="217" width="200" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Task_40" bpmnElement="Task_3">
        <dc:Bounds x="204" y="276" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_29" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_29" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_3">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="254" y="276" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="254" y="81" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="372" y="82" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="251" y="217" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_30" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_30" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_3" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="168" y="316" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="204" y="316" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="182" y="316" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Task_5" bpmnElement="Task_4">
        <dc:Bounds x="1068" y="310" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_31" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_31" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ComplexGateway_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_5">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="890" y="349" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1068" y="350" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="936" y="311" width="123" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_4" bpmnElement="EndEvent_2">
        <dc:Bounds x="1500" y="340" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1509" y="381" width="19" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway_5" bpmnElement="ExclusiveGateway_2" isMarkerVisible="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="1308" y="332" width="50" height="50" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1296" y="310" width="105" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_14" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_14" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway_5" targetElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1333" y="382" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1333" y="459" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="928" y="460" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1136" y="459" width="105" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_BoundaryEvent_7" bpmnElement="BoundaryEvent_6">
        <dc:Bounds x="1099" y="372" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1114" y="413" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_23" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_23" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_BoundaryEvent_7" targetElement="_BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway_5">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1117" y="408" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1117" y="437" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1248" y="437" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1248" y="356" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1308" y="357" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1129" y="406" width="118" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_24" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_24" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway_5" targetElement="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1358" y="357" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1500" y="358" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1390" y="358" width="84" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_2" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_2" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_Task_5" targetElement="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1118" y="310" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1118" y="296" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1334" y="296" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1517" y="296" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1518" y="340" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1271" y="296" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_4" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_4" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ComplexGateway_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="840" y="343" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="799" y="332" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="642" y="332" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="606" y="332" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="556" y="348" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="624" y="304" width="134" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_13" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_13" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_4" targetElement="_BPMNShape_ComplexGateway_2">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="878" y="420" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="878" y="396" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="865" y="396" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="865" y="374" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="870" y="396" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_1" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4" targetElement="_BPMNShape_SendTask_2">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="456" y="364" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="374" y="363" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="374" y="414" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="371" y="387" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_SendTask_2" bpmnElement="SendTask_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="312" y="414" width="124" height="92" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_Lane_12" bpmnElement="Lane_1" isHorizontal="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="102" y="577" width="1483" height="529" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_2" bpmnElement="ParallelGateway_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="408" y="745" width="50" height="50" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="433" y="800" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_3" bpmnElement="ParallelGateway_2">
        <dc:Bounds x="841" y="718" width="50" height="50" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_ReceiveTask_2" bpmnElement="ReceiveTask_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="228" y="618" width="124" height="92" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_UserTask_11" bpmnElement="UserTask_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="564" y="618" width="124" height="92" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_UserTask_12" bpmnElement="UserTask_3">
        <dc:Bounds x="528" y="829" width="124" height="92" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_3" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_3" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_SendTask_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_ReceiveTask_2">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="374" y="506" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="374" y="550" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="290" y="550" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="290" y="618" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="325" y="550" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_5" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_5" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ReceiveTask_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_2">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="352" y="664" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="380" y="664" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="380" y="770" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="408" y="770" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="377" y="695" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_6" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_6" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_11">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="433" y="745" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="433" y="664" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="564" y="664" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="438" y="664" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_7" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_7" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_2" targetElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_12">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="433" y="795" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="433" y="875" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="528" y="875" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="476" y="875" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_8" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_8" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_11" targetElement="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_3">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="688" y="664" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="866" y="664" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="866" y="718" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="823" y="664" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_9" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_9" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_12" targetElement="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_3">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="652" y="875" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="746" y="875" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="866" y="875" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="866" y="768" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="809" y="875" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_10" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_10" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_ParallelGateway_3" targetElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="891" y="743" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1007" y="743" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1007" y="630" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="878" y="630" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="878" y="500" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="1003" y="743" width="6" height="6" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_BoundaryEvent_8" bpmnElement="BoundaryEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="635" y="692" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_BoundaryEvent_9" bpmnElement="BoundaryEvent_2">
        <dc:Bounds x="605" y="903" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_11" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_11" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_BoundaryEvent_8" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="653" y="728" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="653" y="758" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="768" y="758" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="768" y="697" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="783" y="660" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="768" y="631" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="768" y="594" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="768" y="363" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="556" y="364" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="670" y="733" width="73" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_17" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_17" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_BoundaryEvent_9" targetElement="_BPMNShape_Task_4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="623" y="939" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="623" y="969" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="489" y="969" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="489" y="660" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="489" y="529" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="508" y="529" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="506" y="404" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="528" y="938" width="73" height="22" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

What i'm missing?

PD: no errors in the stack trace
**i figured out what is the problem**
-first is processes.xml 
-second in processes.xml the process-archive name property and the bpmn file didn't match so changed that too.

Comment: Please post your bpmn file

Comment: Did you install Camunda exactly as mentioned in the tutorial?

Comment: @Zelldon Done, added the bpmn file

Comment: @thorben yes i did followed the tutorial exactly as they say, the problem begins when i try to model my own process, if load the source code from the example they deploy normally.